# Ftp camera pics to raspberry pi with usb stick

Tags: linux, ftp, raspbian, ip-camera

I try to put the camera pictures (external ip camera) to a raspberry pi that I added to my network. The OS is Raspbian and I mounted a usb stick 16G for the pictures.

The problem is that I provided the camera the correct settings (check screenshot), but instead of putting the pictures on the usb stick, it just creates the path in my home folder. What do I forget? Thanks.

Some additional info:

Partial output of `fdisk` command:

```
Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     8064 31240703 31232640 14.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Folder user, group and permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi 4096 Feb 21 14:28 FTP
```

[image]

Comment: I'd assume this is a problem with your FTP server, rather than the IP Camera. Check the home directory for your FTP server config for this user is on the USB stick.

Comment: Have you checked that you can open this FTP location from another device on the network? Have you checked it from another program (`ftp`, `curl` or a browser) on the pi? Where is the home directory in which the snaps are created? Could you link from this to the pi's USB?

Comment: Jonno, AFH, I checked my user 'Pi'. He is in the passwd list and has a home directory. Everything seems normal. The home directory where the snaps are created is: /home/pi/mnt/usb1/FTP/. 
But that is not what I want. I want the snaps going to /mnt/usb1/FTP. If they go to /home/pi/mnt/usb/FTP the fill my flash card with Raspian on it and with limited place. If they go to /mnt/usb1/FTP then the pics are on the usb stick with 16G storage.

Comment: Ok I checked the folder permissions of my usb in /media and in /mnt. Both have user:pi and group:pi. So that should be ok. I admit in /media it was not the case. Tested again but here also it creates by itself a folder under /home/pi/mnt/usb1 and stores the pics under that folder. It's not on the usb that I mounted on /mnt/usb1...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. A friend told me to create a new user/group for the ftp service and map the home dir of this new user to the usb stick. That's what I did and it works. I also 'chown' and 'chgrp' recursively the mounted map of the usb stick to the new user and group that I created. But this last action was only possible after formatting the usb stick in ext4 because it seems you can't change the owner and group of a stick formatted in FAT32. 
Now,... the path is created in the correct place... but my snapshots are still not there though. I think that is another issue. Not related to this one. I'll look further why my pics are not coming through. If needed I'll open a new threath with more info.